# C Language: why c language has 'class'?

Tags: c, class

In `X86.h` header File, there are `class` declarations. what does it means?
why C language has '`class`?

[image]

Comment: Not C. check `namespace`....

Comment: The code in that image seems to be belonging to [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) which is coded in C++. Just because a header file has the ending `.h` doesn't mean it's automatically a C header file. The `h` simply stands for "Header".

Comment: That's C++ not C...

Comment: Put correct formatting. Post your code, not an image.

Comment: that's why you should read C/C++ together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C language does not have a `class` keyword.

That is a header file for C++, not for C. C++ *does* have a `class` keyword.